# c# ambiguity error

Tags: c#, ambiguity

I am new to C# from java and am getting an error regarding ambiguity. Please let me know what needs to be corrected.

```
public class JessiahP3 
{
    boolean  isPlaying =  false;
    int strings  = 1;
    boolean isTuned = false;
    public String instrumentName;

    //is tuned
    public void isTuned() 
    {
        isTuned = true;
        System.out.println("Currently tuning " + getInstrumentName());
    }

    //not tuned
    public void isNotTuned() 
    {
        isTuned = false;
        System.out.println(getInstrumentName() + " is not tuned");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the precise error message?

Comment: Would be helpful if you said where the `ambiguity` error happens, buddy.

Comment: `System.out.println` is from Java. This isn't C# code.

Comment: @DBM lol good spot. No idea what's going on here.

Comment: Welcome to C#. You'll enjoy writing programs via it.

Answer (score 6):

You have a variable and function named isTuned.

Comment: Error says ambuguity between JessiahP3.isTuned and JessiahP3.isTuned(). @DBM I had changed the println statement there is no error there. Only with the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

Might I suggest the following as more idiomatic C#.

1. Use properties instead of public fields.
2. Prefer automatic getter/setters for properties when appropriate.
3. Properties names should begin with capitals
4. Explicitly specify visibility

--

```
public class JessiahP3
{
    private int strings  = 1;
    public string InstrumentName { get; set; }
    public boolean IsPlaying { get; set; }
    public boolean IsTuned { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a field and a method with the same signature. See `isTuned`.

Answer (score 1):

I see three obvious errors here.

1. You have `isTuned` used as both a variable and a method name within the same type.
2. `System.out.println` will need to be `Console.WriteLine`.
3. `boolean` should be `bool` (or `Boolean`)

That being said, in C#, this would often be done as a single property (along with changing `getInstrumentName()` to an `InstrumentName` property):

```
bool isTuned = false;

bool IsTuned
{
    get { return isTuned; }
    set 
    { 
         this.isTuned = value; 
         Console.WriteLine( isTuned ? "Currently tuning " + this.InstrumentName : this.InstrumentName + " is not tuned" );
    } 
}
```